# How can I add phpMyAdmin in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

Hello everyone I have this docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gestionParking
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    networks:
      - laravel
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

And I want to add phpMyAdmin to have graphical interface of my database, I try this but it doesn't work.

```
...
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gestionParking
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

 phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

I think it's possible, but I think I'm going about it wrong.
I know we need to make a connection between mysql service and phpmyadmin but I don't know how to do it.

Can I help me please

Comment: Shouldn't you open the 3306 port on the phpmyadmin container ?

Comment: you think I should put 3306 on the phpMyAdmin container, instead of 8081

Comment: nvm, but dockerhub phpmyadmin says that phpmyadmin will listen on http://localhost:8080 , so try open "8080:8080"

Comment: Yes, but in 8080 I have, the homepage of laravel, otherwise laravel I change and put it in 8081

Comment: It won't work on the same port. It works like "local:remote". Than try 8081:8080
on phpmyadmin container. So, in theory, you visit localhost:8081 which will map to the phpmyadmin container's 8080 port

Comment: What exactly happens (the "it doesn't work" part)? Do you get an error, does the container start but you can't access it, does it start but exit right away, etc?

Answer (score 0):

version: '3'
services:

```
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.17
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "9998:80"
    volumes:
        - ../:/var/www
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    container_name: php
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ../:/var/www
        - ~:/home
        - ./php-config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

app:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: hakase-labs/laravel
container_name: app
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
environment:
SERVICE_NAME: app
SERVICE_TAGS: dev
working_dir: /var/www/html
volumes:
- ./:/var/www/html
networks:
- mynet

```
composer:
    container_name: composer
    image: composer:1.9.0
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
        - ../:/var/www

mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --max-allowed-packet=64M --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
    volumes:
        # Mount mysl data directory to keep it perisstent on host system.
        # Use this only in development environment
        # Mysql cannot write to data folder as it is owned by user on host.
        # So chown 999:999 data folder when it is first created
        # Todo: For some reason we are not able to mount log directory from host to mysql container. We need to fix this in future so that we can better manage mysql logs from host machine - Harsha
        #- ~/storage/mysql/log:/var/log/mysql
        - ~/storage/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql

    environment:
        - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pasword"
        - "MYSQL_DATABASE=name"
        - "MYSQL_USER=name"
        - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=password"
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"

phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
        - PMA_HOST=mysql
        - PMA_PORT=3306
    ports:
        - 8001:80
    volumes:
        - /sessions
```